# Batch - How to rename a file with information contained in it?

Tags: batch-file

I need to rename `.txt` files with information contained in them. I can't make the `ren` command works. The remaining code seems correct, the 'string' is correct too.
Any help and remark is welcome. Thank you.

EDIT: the `ren` command isn't working but instead displaying "Filename already exists, or can't find the file".
If I replace `ren "%%F" !string!` by `ren "%%F" "example.txt"` the first `.txt` file of my folder will be correctly renamed.

```
@echo off
pause

Set "ActualFolder=D:\folder"

cd /d %ActualFolder%

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR %%F IN (*.txt) DO (

    echo.

    ECHO Previous name: %%F

    FOR /F "tokens=5" %%T IN ('FINDSTR  /C:"name1" %%F') DO (
        SET "n1=%%T"
    )
    FOR /F "tokens=3" %%T IN ('FINDSTR /C:"name2" %%F') DO (
        SET "n2=%%T"
    )
    FOR /F "tokens=5" %%T IN ('FINDSTR  /C:"name3" %%F') DO (
        SET "n3=%%T"
    )

    SET string="!n1! !n2! !n3!.txt"
    echo New name: !string!
    ren "%%F" !string!
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: So - what doesn't "work"? Please show relevant sample contents of the file in question.

Comment: I can't show you sample but the content I'm extracting from the .txt file is just date, time, name. I edited the post with more details.

Comment: Please show some examples of the values of "string"

Comment: The strings follow this pattern : "TEXT1 text2 text-3 2017-07-31 15:22:16.txt"

Comment: If the time stems from your `n3` variable I suggest you change the line `SET string="!n1! !n2! !n3!.txt"`  to `SET string="!n1! !n2! !n3::=_!.txt"` or replace the underscore with another legal char, the colon is allowed in a file name only following the drive letter.

Comment: Thank you LotPings,you are right. It is working now. Sorry for this noob question.